# Update field with default constraint value

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

If a column has a default constraint on it, how do I update existing records to set it to that default value?

e.g. I want to do something like

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = DEFAULT(col1)
WHERE col2 = xxx
```

Comment: Simply `SET col1 = DEFAULT`?

Comment: Add some sample data and datatype of col1, You will have to drop constraint and do a single update or it will not allow update on a default value column

Comment: @Ven what do you mean? You can update a column with a default. The default means "if no other value is provided then use this value". It doesn't mean "no other value is allowed".

Comment: @SeanLange  : Sean you right, i have interpreted it as identity column

Comment: `DEFAULT` is a keyword you can use when issuing updates and inserts to explicitly indicate you want the default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set as following:

```
UPDATE table1
 SET col1 = DEFAULT
 WHERE col2 = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 Create table tab1(id int, def int constraint df_def Default 10)

INSERT INTO tab1(id) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO tab1(id,def) VALUES(2,15)

DECLARE @DefVal INT

SELECT @DefVal=REPLACE(REPLACE(object_definition(default_object_id),'(',''),')','')
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  name      ='def'
AND    object_id = object_id('dbo.tab1')

UPDATE tab1 SET def=@DefVal WHERE id=2
```